# SmartGWT ListGrid doesnt appear below SelectItem

Tags: combobox, smartgwt, listgrid

i know that there are many examples how to show SelectItem / ComboBox records in grid, so I serched over two days for solution but so far I havnt found out where is my mistake. Well what I triyng do is to add some data in ListGrid which will appear when in SelectItem. But the problem is That my grid doesnt appear. Let me show you a bit source :

```
      final SelectItem item = new SelectItem("id1", "Item1");
      final ListGrid grid = new ListGrid();
      grid.setShowAllColumns(true);
      grid.setShowAllRecords(true);
      grid.setShowEmptyMessage(true);
      grid.setShowRowNumbers(true);

      final ListGridField fieldOne = new ListGridField("number", "Number");
      final ListGridField fieldTwo = new ListGridField("time", "Time");
      grid.setFields(new ListGridField[]{fieldOne, fieldTwo});

      AsyncService service = getAsyncService();
      service.getData(new AsyncCallback<List<String[]>>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
          SC.warn("ERROR");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<String[]> result) {      
            final ListGridRecord[] records = new ListGridRecord[result.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                final ListGridRecord record = new ListGridRecord();
                record.setAttribute("number", result.get(i)[1]);
                record.setAttribute("time", result.get(i)[2]);
                records[i] = record;
            }
           grid.setRecords(records);
        }
      });
      item.setPickListProperties(grid);
```

So whats аm I wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: Just make sure that you're not setting any of the attribute to null in the record.

Comment: I dont have any NULL attributes.